# Launch Android Activity directly in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

During development, I want to create run configurations for several activities within my App, so that I can go directly to the Activity I want to test.

But when I create a new Run configuration the list corresponding to "Launch Action" contains only the MAIN Activity and not the others.

Following @sparkymats suggestion I tried adding an IntentFilter to AndroidManifest.xml (either empty or with a  android.intent.category.LAUNCHER category), but the Activity list still only contains the MAIN Activity.

How can I directly launch other activities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, you will need to modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add an `IntentFilter` to each one you want to launch directly. An `Activity` is launched by sending an Intent to it. So, the `Activity` must be configured to receive `Intent`s from the launcher.

Answer (score 6):

In the Manifest file, put these lines inside each activity's tag that you want to lunch

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```